# Print working directory into output filename

Tags: string, bash, output

I am currently running a bash script which executes and outputs the results. The output logs are currently stored with the {basename}.out. For example,

`home/usr/dev` stored as `dev.out`.

However, I want to name the file as the full working printing directory such as `home_usr_dev.out`

How can I rename the file to the full path or working directory?

Comment: soo `cd home/usr/dev` and then `mv dev.out home_usr_dev.out` ?

Comment: Why contains `home/usr/dev` no leading `/`?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, doing this manually just amounts to using the `cd` and `mv` shell builtins.

But if you want to automate the "computation" of the output filename in Bash, assuming `$path` (in lowercase!) denotes the full path of the input file or directory, you can do:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
out_file() {
  local tmp="$1"
  tmp="${tmp#/}"      # remove leading `/`
  tmp="${tmp//\//_}"  # replace all `/`s with `_`s
  printf "%s" "$tmp"
}
path="/home/usr/dev"
# or path="$PWD"  # if you want to use the current working directory

out="$(out_file "$path").out"  # on this example, gives "home_usr_dev.out"

echo "Logs…" >> "$out"         # append "Logs…" to file ./home_usr_dev.out
```

For the sake of completeness, note that the `${tmp//\//_}` phrasing corresponds to [a Pattern Substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace) (which is available in Bash but not in POSIX shell), and it can be parsed like this (assuming spaces as ignored):

```
${tmp // \/ / _}
   ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓ ↓
   ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓ the character _.
   ↓  ↓  ↓  with
   ↓  ↓  of / (escape needed here)
   ↓  then replace all occurrences  
   Get the value of $tmp,
```